# How to be superuser in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 12.04, installation, 11.10, 13.04, 13.10

To install a `.run` file I am using

```
su -
```

to be super user in `terminal`,it asks for password but on entering password it show following error

```
su: Authentication failure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with `sudo -i` or simply `sudo ./yourCommand` (or something like that: `sudo sh yourCommand` ....)? Notice that, unless you've changed it, in Ubuntu you don't know root password.

Cheers and merry Christmas,

Silvia

Comment: Thanks this worked 
`
sudo chmod +x filename.run
sudo ./filename.run`

Comment: user3109712, if you don't know the passwd, you could use `sudo -i` and then `passwd` to change it - and it's not quite Christmas yet @silvia :-D

Comment: @wilf ... :-D I know, but tomorrow I'll be playing multiple roles (wifeCaringHerHusband, momCaringHerChild, super-cookPreparingXMasEveSupper, ... and so on, until momMaskedAsSanta! :-D ) so I won't be here, I fear :-D

So merry XMas to you too! :-D

Comment: @user3109712: you're welcome!

Comment: Merry Christmas then! :-D